# hash functions and hash tables

Tags: hashtable

I have been assigned a question dealing with hash tables and hash functions and I am currently stuck on how to assign the size using the function given.

I was given the problem that h(n) = n/10 which is simple enough

Then I am told that the size is 10, and I have to insert numbers given to me into a list.

My problem is that I thought the array that I put these numbers would be from 0-9. My numbers are 352, 4079, 25, 251, 498, 591, 242 which confuses me more because if I do say something like 4079/10 that is way more than 9 so I cannot put that in the array....

I think I am probably missing something huge here, but I don't know what.

Comment: h(n)  % n   ..............  % == modulo

Comment: I don't know what the % means.